# Can a coil of wire levitate over another, if so how?

Tags: electromagnetism, levitation

I have been looking at Maxwell's equations (intergral form it's easier to understand):
$$
\\\iint_{\partial\Omega}E\cdot dS = \frac{1}{\epsilon_{0}}\iiint\rho\cdot dV
\\\iint_{\partial\Omega}B\cdot dS = 0
\\\oint_{\partial\Sigma}E\cdot dl = -\frac{d}{dt}\iint_{\Sigma}B\cdot dS
\\\oint_{\partial\Sigma}B\cdot dl = \mu_{0}(\iint_{\Sigma} J\cdot dS +\epsilon_{0}\frac{d}{dt}\iint_{\Sigma}E\cdot dS)
$$

The equations tell me that I can have a coil with ac current going in and the other coil will make a magnetic field opposing the original field, so with enough energy you can make the second induction coil levitate. am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but Earnshaw's theorem says you'd need it to be active (compensating for position and velocity "errors", typically done by computer) rather than passive (not using feedback). Otherwise it will fall over the hump of repulsion. And, of course, you'd need a few more coils to make those corrections.

Generally, the coils would be parallel with opposite currents.

Comment: so it would work but it is unstable in reality

Comment: Oh its been done, but it took a PID loop in software to do it.

Comment: Earnshaw's theorem can be circumvented in spinning systems

Comment: @Dirk, you have to have diamagnetism/sustainable eddy currents--that's why superconductors can passively levitate (they can sustain eddy currents forever--without energy loss). Spinning magnets, even if electromagnetic, will not be stable because the eddy currents are not automatically (actively) adjusted to restore position.

Comment: @Digiproc, here's someone doing it with spinning: https://youtu.be/hu1jEWLZVug, although this uses a magnet rather than a coil.

Comment: @Digiproc A spinning magnet can be stable due to precession. When calculating the adiabatic potential (that is averaging over the precession assumed to be fast) one gets that effectively only the $z$-component of the magnetic field enters, and a minimum in the $z$-component can easily be achieved. The parameter space where this is possible is however quite small and even the magnetization differences due to room temperature changes make it necesssary to adjust of the mass of the levitating magnet.

Comment: Note that this process is not even dissipative in itself. Dissipation is primarily due to air friction (which will cause the magnet to drop after some time). Ceramic magnets have a conductivity of about zero.

Comment: Its cool, but this still falls under the theoretically "unstable" category because it takes advantage of the fact that there is a dampening of the corrective movements (air resistance, magnetic hysteresis, etc.) that is ~necessary~ to extend the time the object is levitated. Without that dampening, the object would fall sooner because you wouldn't get the proper PID constants. In other words, its a simple ~active~ (not passive) process that, to stay stable indefinitely, would still need a continuous supply of energy, even theoretically--because the nonlinear effect of dampening is necessary.

Comment: In other words, its a nonlinear process, and therefore active rather than passive, and thus requires constant energy input.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a sort of "Yes". However, it is a lot easier to use permanent magnets. Also, the escape clause when it comes to Earnshaw's Theorem is to [stabilize by spinning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RbsCiorwzI)